# TinyMCE not displaying bullet points from copy+paste?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

When I bullet something in word, copy it, then paste it into TinyMCE the bold+underline+sizing works but bullet's don't show up.  I have the latest version from their website - on which the copy+pasting of bullets work.

Anyone heard of this?

Comment: Just realized that it works in the advanced version, but not in the stripped down simplified version (which is lighter size wise).

Anyone have any idea how to code this in?

Comment: you mean into the stripped version? why don't you use the full one?

Comment: I could - but I thought this was a lightweight alternative to that.  I guess I'll use the full version and cut away all the features we don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paste plugin performs the filtering which picks up lists.  Without the paste plugin being used you won't get the improved behaviour.  If you want really good word paste functionality take a look at the Ephox power paste plugin (http://tinymce.ephox.com/plugins) -

disclaimer - I work for Ephox

Comment: How much does the Ephox paste plugin cost?